# simple web based editor for documentation of an app

Tags: collaboration

I want a simple html and javascript based web page for editing a single document for documentation of an app that I am making. it should be editable by multiple people if possible asking for a password before it registers. I have ftp access to a web site but that is it. no database. I did not find anything that will point to a single file and just simply edit it without any software requirements. it would be nice if it were mobile friendly too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work for a hosting provider so that is a good question imo. What you are looking for is a flat file storage CMS to avoid a database. Requiring user management and simplicity you will not want to code this from scratch. We deal with alot of CMS (Content Management Systems) and most are bloated and require MySQL.

Check Out: http://get-simple.info/

I fired an installation up and it is very easy to install, has alot of features, and is very WordPress like which means it looks good out of the box and is very easy to use.

I hope this helps you out and if you do use it let me know your thoughts.

Comment: seems great but the editing capability is limited from my mobile browser probably will use if there is nothing better

Comment: realized that the editor works best in firefox.

Comment: here is a post with a question I have about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442339/get-simple-cms-inline-page-editing